# Drawing one graph contains all information of data gathered in different phases and in different treatment groups

Tags: r, graph, linear-regression

I need to draw a graph showing the simple linear relationship between dependent variables Y and independent variables X. The thing is X belongs to different phases and rounds of data collection process, and X also belongs to 2 different treatment groups. I would like to show all in one graph, and what I have in mind is that the vertical axis would still be Y, but the horizontal axis would be "Round";  the lines on the graph would stand for the linear relationships between Y and X for each treatment and phase (so there would be 4 regression lines), and lastly the colors would define the treatments.

Here is a sample data frame:

```
phase <- c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10))
treatment <- c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5), rep("A",5), rep("B",5))
round <- c(rep(seq(1,5,1),2),rep(seq(6,10,1),2))
x <- c(seq(10,18,2),seq(10,2,-2),seq(18,10,-2),seq(2,10,2))
y <- 1+0.5*x

df <- data.frame(phase,treatment,round,x,y)
col <- c("Phase", "Treatment","Round","X","Y")
colnames(df) <- col
df
```

And here is what I have in mind:

Drawing of the graph

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use faceting in `ggplot2` to separate the two plots.
But first I will recreate the data set, in order to have a bit of noise in the points `y` coordinates. The data structure remains the same.

```
set.seed(2020)
phase <- c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10))
treatment <- c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5), rep("A",5), rep("B",5))
round <- c(rep(seq(1,5,1),2),rep(seq(6,10,1),2))
x <- c(seq(10,18,2),seq(10,2,-2),seq(18,10,-2),seq(2,10,2))
y <- 1 + 0.5*x + rnorm(length(x))

df <- data.frame(phase,treatment,round,x,y)
col <- c("Phase", "Treatment","Round","X","Y")
colnames(df) <- col
```

**The plot**

Now the plot. Note that I also change the facets' labels, making them more descriptive.

```
library(ggplot2)

df$Phase <- factor(df$Phase)
phase_names <- c(
  `1` = "Phase 1",
  `2` = "Phase 2"
)

ggplot(df, aes(Round, Y, colour = Treatment)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("A", "B"), values = c("green", "red")) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Phase, labeller = labeller(Phase = as_labeller(phase_names)))
```

[image]

---

After the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65859310/drawing-one-graph-contains-all-information-of-data-gathered-in-different-phases/65859829?noredirect=1#comment116448008_65859829) below, here is the same code but with `x = X`, not `x = Round`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(X, Y, colour = Treatment)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("A", "B"), values = c("green", "red")) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Phase, labeller = labeller(Phase = as_labeller(phase_names)))
```

[image]

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, the axes and colors are correct. But as I see there was no regression line showing the relationship between Y and X on it, and that is my main concern. My real data is more complicated and the data points do not connect with each other to form a straight line like in the provided sample data. So my main question is how to display 4 different regression lines on one graph.

Comment: thank you very much, I didn't notice that geom_smooth could solve this. Have a very good day :D

Comment: Hi @Rui, after some checking, it seems that geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE)  takes y as "Y" and x as "Round", not as "X" as we wanted. I tried to replace (X,Y) with a new a sequence y <- rep(5,20); x <- seq(1,20,1) just right before execute the graph and the graph still stayed the same.

Comment: @nexmaxx Yes, you are right, `geom_smooth` is taking `x = Round`. I have based this on your posted graph, the x axis is labelled `round`. See after the edit, with the original `X` values.